# Associative array not storing mappings

Tags: arrays, opengl, d, associative-array

I'm trying to build a simple 3D-game engine in D using Derelict3. Things have been going smoothly until I started using associative arrays for mapping opengl *glGenTextures*/*glGenBuffers*. For this I constructed a simple struct which contains a reference to the texture/vbo which was to be bound and the id returned from opengl. This was then to be mapped with the hash of the texture/vbo for later retrieval.

However, as soon as it finishes setting up the actual  mapping, the mapping is removed *magically*. I have yet to understand why. Below is a simple example on what I am trying to achieve, and the same behaviour can be observed.

```
module main;

import std.datetime;
import std.stdio;

class Placeholder {
    string value;

    this(string value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}

private class ResourceInfo {
    uint id;   
    uint time;
    Object resource;

    static ResourceInfo getOrCreate(Object resource, ResourceInfo[uint] map) {
        uint hash = resource.toHash();
        ResourceInfo* temp = (hash in map);
        ResourceInfo info;
        if (!temp){
            info = new ResourceInfo();
            info.resource = resource;
            map[hash] = info;
        } else{
            info = *temp;   
        }
        // placeholders.lenght is now 1 (!)
        info.time = stdTimeToUnixTime(Clock.currStdTime);
        return info;
    }
}

protected ResourceInfo[uint] placeholders;

void main() {

    Placeholder value = new Placeholder("test");

    while(true) {
        ResourceInfo info = ResourceInfo.getOrCreate(value, placeholders);
        // placeholders.lenght is now 0 (!)
        if (!info.id) {
            info.id = 1; // Here we call glGenBuffers(1, &info.id); in the     engine
        } else {
            // This never runs
            writeln("FOUND: ", info.id);
        }
    }
}
```

Calling `placeholders[value.toHash()] = info` manually when no *id* exists temporarily fixes it but then I start getting `object.Error: Access Violation` in `_aaApply2` and `_d_delclass` whenever I try to access an instance of `info` after a few seconds.

Anyone seeing anything obvious that I'm missing?

Comment: Could it be that those are allocated by malloc() or similar by some C/C++ library you use from D? Normally GC knows nothing about them, they could be free()d any time you know...

Comment: i don't like how you just drop the type informations for an object, sure, you can cast to it and check if its zero, BUT my way for doing such stuff is to hide the casting and checking with a templated method which should return the type, if the cast fails i would assert false/throw, depends on your style. This way you don't have messy casting code directly in your usage code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best I could **guess** is the usual pseudo-behavior of uninitialized associative arrays. Meaning passing them by value and then adding keys to them works but **only** if that array was already initialized. It's a current edge-case in the implementation. Try using `ref` however, it should fix things:

```
static ResourceInfo getOrCreate(Object resource, ref ResourceInfo[uint] map)
```